# Should symbols like ⌘⌃⇧ be used to describe macOS keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: discussion, formatting

This answer made me think: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42078914/3939277

It uses <kbd>Cmd</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and <kbd>Option</kbd> to describe the modifier keys to hold in a keyboard shortcut.

For questions meant to be read on macOS and executed on macOS:

1. It is OK to use <kbd>⌘</kbd>, <kbd>⇧</kbd>, <kbd>⌥</kbd>, <kbd>⌃</kbd>, etc. to describe macOS modifier keys in questions and answers? These correspond with symbols in menus.
2. If so, is the use of these preferred? Are there any that should be avoided?
3. If not, why not? macOS users should be used to these after only a month or two of use.

Comment: What is on the physical keyboard?  You should try and match that.

Comment: i mean, i guess? why not? are they more descriptive? what's the purpose of this?

Comment: @NathanOliver: **Both** are used, and dependent on the exact Mac keyboard. My laptop has `⌘`/`command` and `alt`/`option`, but the latter is commonly referred to as `⌥` as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What is more common though?  `alt/option` or `⌥`?  I don't really use macs but I've at least seen `alt/option` and not `⌥`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Mac documentation and menu indicators use the symbols, so personally I try to use those. I don't know what is 'common' on the keyboards, I haven't done a survey.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If that's what the menus and docs use then that sounds like a good idea.

Comment: This question reads as if it's asking permission to use mac specific keyboard keys in general, rather than asking which version of a specific key (that doesn't have a consistent name/symbol) should be used.  If it really is asking about the latter, that could be better clarified in the question.  If the former...that seems like it doesn't require an answer.

Comment: @Servy I don't know what you mean by either of those. If you think I have excluded some information, that's not really my style. I really just want to know the answers to those three questions I enumerated.

Comment: No love for [Open Apple and Closed Apple](http://www.macworld.com/article/2867994/think-retro-open-apple-closed-apple.html)?

Comment: @RobertColumbia Sure, if you're asking questions about keyboard shortcuts on an Apple ][ 

Comment: If you turn on the macOS 'keyboard viewer', then the graphic symbols are used on the keyboard layout that it shows.  For clarity, use both symbols and text if you are energetic enough to find the symbols in the 'Emoji and Symbols' tool, but using just the text is OK.  (It may be useful to note that: ⌘ is U+2318 PLACE OF INTEREST SIGN; ⇧ is U+21E7 UPWARDS WHITE ARROW; ⌥ is U+2325 OPTION KEY; ⌃ is U+2303 UP ARROWHEAD.)

Comment: One downside to using symbols instead of spelling out the keys is that such a question or answer would be less likely picked up by search engines. Since a lot of the website's traffic comes from them it may be worth keeping in mind.

Comment: Are you asking if it is just *OK* to use them in some answer/post, or are you asking if there should be an effort for you, or others, to go through posts *changing* them to one way, or another?

Comment: This is attracting some opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They're more awkward to type out for the small subset of PC users who also know the Mac shortcuts, but I personally have no qualms about those symbols being used. They're already fairly ubiquitous.

Comment: Ironically, there's no way to type them directly from a Mac keyboard. They're copy-paste material only. But I do like them better.

Comment: Yeah, that strange irony always made me smirk. I just put them into my favorites in the quick-character thingie that comes up with `⌃` `⌘` `space`

Comment: The symbols ⌥ and ⌃ are not shown my (modern) MacBook Pro keyboard, while "control", "option" and "command" are, so I would prefer the text versions.

Comment: I've been using a Mac for years.  Those symbols do _not_ appear on the keyboard, and I still find I have to look them up when I find a tutorial that uses them.  Would be much more meaningful to use `Command`, etc.

Comment: They're still used but only in certain regions.

Answer (score 4):

Apple documentation makes systematic use of these symbols. It rarely spells them out as command, option, control or shift (and when it does, it's always lowercase).

My opinion is that we should follow Apple usage.

(And in any case, "Cmd" is way more obscure to a Mac user than ⌘. If you want to spell it out, use "command", not "Cmd".)

Answer (score 0):

The first two symbols, the "Command" and "Shift" symbols are commonly know (Even my windows laptop has the shift icon on it). I wouldn't use the option/alt symbol or the ctrl symbol because they are less iconic and less well known.